# web browser in c#

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I am creating a web browser using WebBrowser control in C#. I have no idea how to make my browser a multi tabbed one, Can anyone help me with suggestions, advice or anything . I will be very helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would need to provide your own tabs - these are not included in the WebBrowser control.  You could use an existing tab control and adapt it to your needs.

You can look at something like this for an example:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressvcs/thread/5504a6bb-4232-4b8b-8ae4-33ad2ca8ea81